# Angular Firebase $createUser function returns error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm at an impasse on this.  I'm trying to create a user with AngularFire using $firebaseAuth NOT the deprecated FirebaseSimpleLogin, as recommended in the docs.  I am certain that the form submits a valid email and password, but I continue to get the following error in the console:

`Error: Firebase.createUser failed: First argument must contain the key "email" with type "string"`

You can see the code, I use a factory service to handle the $createUser method, which is where the error is occurring because the subsequent console.logs are not firing once the method returns.  Please note, I have also tried using the boilerplate code in the docs rather than splitting it between controller and services and have received the same error.  Your assistance is greatly appreciated, thanks!

**ng-submit="register()" on Form element**

`$scope.register = function(){
        console.log($scope.user); // logs object correctly
        // Authentication is passed into the controller as a dependency
        Authentication.register($scope.user) 
            .then(function(){
                //This does NOT fire
                console.log("User created successfully!"); 
                Authentication.login($scope.user);

            })
            .then(function(authData){
                console.log("Logged in as:", authData.uid);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log('error');
                $scope.errorMessage = error.toString();
        });
};`

**Authentication factory service**

```
var obj = {
    register: function(user){
        var obj = {email: user.email, password: user.password};
        console.log(obj); // works correctly
        //var auth has the reference to Firebase
        return auth.$createUser(obj);
    }   
};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE: Simply upgrade to AngularFire 0.9.1 or later and this problem will be fixed.**

**UPDATE DETAILS: Using a single credentials parameter (as the original questioner did) is now the suggested way to call this (and the other authentication methods) as of AngularFire 0.9.1. The format described below has been deprecated and will be removed in an upcoming release, so we do no recommend using it.**

This is my fault while writing the documentation. I apologize for the completely understandable confusion. I wanted to keep the API somewhat backwards compatible with the previous AngularFire API and decided to have the user management methods take individual arguments, instead of an object of arguments like the regular Firebase SDK takes. However, the docs (and examples) do not accurately reflect this decision. Your code should look like this:

```
auth.$createUser("test@test.com", "password").then(function() {
  console.log("User created successfully!");
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error:", error);
});
```

I'll get the docs updated immediately but here is the answer to get you unblocked.

Comment: That worked, yeah the docs look like you have to pass an object, especially since $authWithPassword takes an object for login.  Thanks, and Firebase is simply awesome!

Comment: The docs will be fixed by first thing tomorrow (Monday). If you find any other docs issues, please let us know. We try to keep them as accurate as possible but they are constantly being improved. And we may support the ability to pass all the arguments as an object in the future, but I will need to talk to my coworkers about that.

Comment: @qmmr- The docs I was referring to are correct: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-user-authentication-and-management-createuseremail-password. If you think you found an issue somewhere, please provide a link.

Comment: This is actually the correct syntax as of today's 0.9.1 release. :) Both will work but the individual parameters version is now deprecated. It was a mistake for me to ever do individual parameters since the Firebase client does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error. Angularfire 1.1 or later (code at home) (updated with Bower). I'm following the tutorial https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html and are using the code for Managing users.

The code works with hard coded strings eg. user@domain.com. And I aslo found a work around. If I add + '' to the arguments of the object to $Auth.createUser(). I also works. I feels like my posted email/pwsd text as ng-model are not a string?